# GitHub CI/Actions - Cannot find module. Make sure this package is installed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github-pages, github-actions

I want to use absolute import paths with my typescript react app.
Thefore, I've added the `"baseUrl": "./src"` to the `tsconfig.json`.

I can build the app locally with `yard build` but it doesn't work with the Github CI (Actions).

This is the error I get from the CI

```
./src/components/App/App.tsx
Cannot find module: 'constants/Routes'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

I import the component with `import { ROUTES } from 'constants/Routes'`. Using `./constants/Routes` instead doesn't work with the set baseUrl.

I got the same error using the `.`, `src` baseUrl.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Action.yml

```
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, feature/*]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.1

      - name: Install and Build 
        run: |
          yarn --frozen-lockfile
          yarn build

      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.5
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: build
```

Comment: I'm also experiencing this. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @IronSean Yes, I‘ve had renamed that folder from capital latter to lowercase letter. It turned out, that git didn’t get these changes. Try cloning your repository again and have a look at the folder and file names, if they are named like they should. If not, remove them and add them again to your repository. After that my git got these changes and this problem was resolved.

Comment: In my case the issue ended up being that a new file I added was in a folder ignored by a .gitignore rule, so the build worked locally but the file was missing in the repo/on the CI server. Thanks for replying so if others find this in the future they'll have some clues.