# NextJS Standalone Export Buildspec Error "Module not found: Can't resolve component" in CodeBuild

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg, aws-codepipeline, codebuild

I have the following buildspec running via CodePipeline/CodeBuild

```
version: 0.2

phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            nodejs: 18
    pre_build:
        commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - cd webConsole
            - npm install -g yarn
            - yarn install
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on $(date)
            - yarn build
    post_build:
        commands:
            - aws s3 cp --recursive --acl public-read ./out s3://<S3_BUCKET>
            - aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control="max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" ./out/index.html s3://<S3_BUCKET
            - aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id <CLOUDFRONT DISTRO> --paths /*
artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
        - "**/*"
cache:
    paths:
        - node_modules/**/*
```

I am running the same steps locally and it is working fine with the same version of node. I'm wondering if anyone has seen the same thing in the CodeBuild stage of a pipeline. The install works fine, but I am getting the following errors in the build stage

```
./src/components/Login.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './misc/CustomCheckbox'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

I have checked my imports are using the correct casing, and the CustomCheckbox is just a styled MUI Checkbox.,

The nextjs build is a standalone build with the following config

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
    output: "export",
    trailingSlash: true,
    optimizeFonts: false,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### solution

1. clone the repository again,
2. compare the cases of folder/filenames in both the repositories

for files:

- use `git mv filename to Filename`

for folders:

- rename folder entirely to another name
- git commit the changes
- rename the folder to the name u want
- git commit the changes

#### description

i had the same. i could run the build locally without trouble,
but in github action i had the "module not found error" for my own components of the project. i compared with 2 other projects on same tech-stack and they were building fine.

i found out it has nothing to do with the actual file import in your project, neither with the nextjs.config

It turns out `git` does not track the change of a folder/file if just it's `case` changed (depends on case-sensitivity of your/remote file system) after it was already checked in. In my case i renamed `Components` folder to `components` folder and it was not tracked.

[image: module not found: in git action]

#### other answers

[Github Actions for NodeJS - 'Error: Cannot find module' for local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336306/github-actions-for-nodejs-error-cannot-find-module-for-local-filet)

[GitHub CI/Actions - Cannot find module. Make sure this package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319210/github-ci-actions-cannot-find-module-make-sure-this-package-is-installed)

[Case sensitivity in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904327/case-sensitivity-in-git)

Comment: Awesome! Good pick up. Seems like this has worked. I wrote a powershell script to recursively update all the names for a file if you need to do it recursively

`Get-ChildItem -Path .\src\components\Misc -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $childFile = $_.FullName -replace '^.*\\Misc\\', 'src\components\misc\'
    git mv -f $_.FullName $childFile
}`